# How to check the values of the payload variable which was received by server

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am working on a research project for which I need to parse data from a website tapology.com. The problem is that the necessary data can be extracted by sending a post request with the payload variable.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
payload = {'group':'all','shedule':'results','sport':'mma','region':''}
url = 'https://tapology.com/fightcenter'
with requests.Session as s:
    s.headers.update({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8','Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7','Content-Length':'161','Host':'www.tapology.com','Origin':'https://www.tapology.com','Referer':'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter','sec-ch-ua':'"Not:A-Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="112"','sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?1','sec-ch-ua-platform':'"Android"','Sec-Fech-Dest':'empty','Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors','Sec-Fetch-Site':'same-origin','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-M127F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36','X-Requested-Width':'XMLHttpRequest'})

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    payload['authenticity_token'] = soup.select_one("input[name='authenticity_token']")['value']
    x = payload['authenticity_token']
    s.headers.update({'X-CSRF-Token': str(x)})
    data_source = 'https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter_events'
    res = s.post(data_source,  data = payload)
    item = soup.find_all('section',class_='fcListing')
    for i in item:
        sport = i.select('span.sport')
        print(sport)
```

I am expecting that `print(sport)` will output MMA for each retriving results because in payload variable for **sport** key i specified **mma** as value. But print statement give me mixed results (MMA, Boxing etc). Its obvious that problem with payload variable which maybe not accepted   or wrongly recognized by server. Can i check what data was received by a server? Can anyone give me advice how  i can debug my problem

Comment: Did you notice the TypeError exception that was raised when to tried to run this? Also, given the way this website is constructed you'll probably want to use *selenium* (or something else with functionality that supports dynamic websites)

Answer (score 0):

To get the information from the page you can use their pagination Ajax API:

```py
import re
from html import unescape
from ast import literal_eval
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    'Accept': '*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript'
}

for p in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    url = f"https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter_events?page={p}"
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

    data = re.search(r'html\((.*)\);', data).group(1)
    data = unescape(literal_eval(data)).replace('\/', '/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

    for s in soup.select('section.fcListing'):
        name = s.select_one('.name').get_text(strip=True)
        dt = s.select_one('.datetime').get_text(strip=True)
        print(f'{name:<50} {dt}')
```

Prints:

```
...

Full Contact Contender 34                          Saturday, June 17, 12:00 PM ET
Eagle FC 52                                        Saturday, June 17, 12:00 PM ET
Cage Warriors Academy: Lowlands 6                  Saturday, June 17, 12:00 PM ET
Open Fighting Championship                         Saturday, June 17, 12:00 PM ET
Roar Fighting Championship 27                      Saturday, June 17, 12:00 PM ET
MMA Series 69                                      Saturday, June 17, 12:00 PM ET
```